# Cake PHP Plugin Call Routing Problems

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a strange behavior within my CakePHP.

I have created different Plugins, and for some Plugins I have created a Setting Page.

Call is like:

[url]/plugin_one/admin/setting

[url]/plugin_two/admin/setting

Links are created this way:

```
$this->Html->link("Setting1", array("plugin" => "plugin_one", "controller" => "admin", "action" => "setting"));
$this->Html->link("Setting2", array("plugin" => "plugin_two", "controller" => "admin", "action" => "setting"));
```

So far so good.

It is working, when I click "Setting1" I get the Setting Page for Plugin One, if I click "Setting2" I get the Setting Page for Plugin Two.

BUT:

If I have opened the Settings Page for Plugin One and then try to open the Settings Page for Plugin Two, somehow the Admin Controller of "Plugin One" is called, with the View of "Plugin Two".

Since I set the page title in the controllers action "setting" I see this strange behavior.

```
$this->set("title_for_layout", "Plugin One - Settings");
```

Within my "setting" action, I get the Plugin's setting data, too:

```
$this->request->data = $settings["plugin_one"];
```

So for example, I am on the Settings Page of Plugin One, my page title is "Plugin One - Settings", my page contents are the different settings options of "Plugin One".

Now I try to open the Settings Page of "Plugin Two", and my page title is "Plugin One - Settings", my page content are the different settings options of "Plugin Two", but I do not get the settings data from the model, because my request data is the request data of "Plugin One", too.

The funny thing is, this happens the same way around.

If I have opend the "Plugin Two" Settings Page and then try to open the "Plugin One" Settings Page, it's the same thing around. Now I would see the "Plugin Two - Settings" title on my "Plugin One" Settings Page with the "Plugin Two" request data.

I think there is some internal routing trouble, what do you think?

Edit:

I use the "Debug Toolbar" Plugin, too.
If I call "Plugin One" Settings, within the "Debug Toolbar" -> "Include" -> "Plugins" I see "Plugin One".
Now I call "Plugin Two" Settings, and within the "Debug Toolbar" -> "Include" -> "Plugins" I see "Plugin One".

Edit #2:

If I wait about 5 minutes (one cigarette ;-)) and hit F5, the "Plugin Two" Settings Page is loaded correctly, and within the "Debug Toolbar" -> "Include" -> "Plugins" I see "Plugin Two"

Might there be an internal caching problem, if I use different Plugins with the same Controller and Action names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution:

Renamed the Controller ...

plugin_one/admin => plugin_one/poAdmin
plugin_two/admin => plugin_two/ptAdmin

etc ...

Now it works ... seems like CakePHP does not like multiple same namend controllers within different plugins